# How to validate multiple output from SOAP response

Tags: soap, karate

I am trying to validate the XML SOAP response below, but it's not working. Please let me know the correct approach. Please let me know if more info is needed.

**Response XML:**

```
<GetTariffsInfoResult>
  <Status>
    <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
    <StatusDescription>SUCCESS</StatusDescription>
  </Status>
  <OutputParameterSets>
    <OutputParameterSet>
      <OutputParameters>
        <OutputParameter>
          <Name>COMP_AVAILABLE</Name>
          <Value>TRUE</Value>
        </OutputParameter>
        <OutputParameter>
          <Name>ILEC_VENDORNAME</Name>
          <Value>COMP1</Value>
        </OutputParameter>
        <OutputParameter>
          <Name>ABC</Name>
          <Value>FALSE</Value>
        </OutputParameter>
        <OutputParameter>
          <Name>TEST</Name>
          <Value>Identical</Value>
        </OutputParameter>
      </OutputParameters>
    </OutputParameterSet>
  </OutputParameterSets>
</GetTariffsInfoResult>
```

**feature**

```
    Scenario: Check Request and Respone xml

     * set /Envelope/Body/GetTariffsInfoResponse/GetTariffsInfoResult
              | Path                | Value   |
              | OutputParameter[1]/Name  | 'QOS_AVAILABLE'   |
            | OutputParameter[1]/Value | 'True'  |
            | OutputParameter[2]/Name  | 'ILEC_VENDORNAME'   |
            | OutputParameter[2]/Value | 'CENTURYTEL OF MW-WISCONSIN LLC  DBA CENTURYLINK - NORTH'  |
            | OutputParameter[3]/Name  | 'QC'   |
            | OutputParameter[3]/Value | 'FALSE'  |
            | OutputParameter[4]/Name  | 'ELA_PREMIER_TYPE'   |
            | OutputParameter[4]/Value | 'Identical'  |
            | OutputParameter[5]/Name  | 'QOS_ALIGNMENT'   |
            | OutputParameter[5]/Value | 'Y'  |
            | OutputParameter[6]/Name  | 'QOS_IDENTICAL'   |
            | OutputParameter[6]/Value | 'Y'  |
            | OutputParameter[7]/Name  | 'QOS_MEDIUM'   |
            | OutputParameter[7]/Value | 'Y'  |
            | OutputParameter[8]/Name  | 'QOS_NONE'   |
            | OutputParameter[8]/Value | 'Y'  | 
            #|path



        Given request read('request.xml')
        When soap action 'XYZ'
        Then status 200
        And match /Envelope/Body/GetTariffsInfoResponse/GetTariffsInfoResult/Status/StatusCode == 0
        And match /Envelope/Body/GetTariffsInfoResponse/GetTariffsInfoResult == read('Excepted.xml')
        And print 'response: ', response
    And match / == read('Excepted.xml')
```

In this feature everything is passing only last step is failing "And match / == read('Excepted.xml')". which is throwing actual as '(not present')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, in the future, simplify your example and don't dump your whole work here like this.

When you do `match /` you are trying to match the FULL XML starting from the root. I recommend you just match the parts you need and make life simple.

You can cut and paste the below into a new `Scenario:` and try it. You will see one mistake you made is the table columns `path` and `value` should be lower-case. I have also shown you how you can use XML itself as expected results instead of painfully creating a table. Read the documentation carefully and also refer to this file for good examples: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)

```
* def response = 
"""
<GetTariffsInfoResult>
   <Status>
      <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
      <StatusDescription>SUCCESS</StatusDescription>
   </Status>
   <OutputParameterSets>
      <OutputParameterSet>
         <OutputParameters>
            <OutputParameter>
               <Name>COMP_AVAILABLE</Name>
               <Value>TRUE</Value>
            </OutputParameter>
            <OutputParameter>
               <Name>ILEC_VENDORNAME</Name>
               <Value>COMP1</Value>
            </OutputParameter>
            <OutputParameter>
               <Name>ABC</Name>
               <Value>FALSE</Value>
            </OutputParameter>
            <OutputParameter>
               <Name>TEST</Name>
               <Value>Identical</Value>
            </OutputParameter>
         </OutputParameters>
      </OutputParameterSet>
   </OutputParameterSets>
</GetTariffsInfoResult>
"""

* set expected /OutputParameters
    | path                     | value   |
    | OutputParameter[1]/Name  | 'COMP_AVAILABLE'   |
    | OutputParameter[1]/Value | 'TRUE'  |
    | OutputParameter[2]/Name  | 'ILEC_VENDORNAME'   |
    | OutputParameter[2]/Value | 'COMP1'  |
    | OutputParameter[3]/Name  | 'ABC'   |
    | OutputParameter[3]/Value | 'FALSE'  |
    | OutputParameter[4]/Name  | 'TEST'   |
    | OutputParameter[4]/Value | 'Identical'  |

* match /GetTariffsInfoResult/OutputParameterSets/OutputParameterSet/OutputParameters == expected

* match /GetTariffsInfoResult/OutputParameterSets/OutputParameterSet/OutputParameters == 
    """
     <OutputParameters>
        <OutputParameter>
           <Name>COMP_AVAILABLE</Name>
           <Value>TRUE</Value>
        </OutputParameter>
        <OutputParameter>
           <Name>ILEC_VENDORNAME</Name>
           <Value>COMP1</Value>
        </OutputParameter>
        <OutputParameter>
           <Name>ABC</Name>
           <Value>FALSE</Value>
        </OutputParameter>
        <OutputParameter>
           <Name>TEST</Name>
           <Value>Identical</Value>
        </OutputParameter>
     </OutputParameters>
    """
```

Comment: Why this query is rejected. Please let me know, as im struck.